# Mapping Command key to Control key not working for mac

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout, mac

I am trying to map Command key to Control key, and Option key to Meta key in Emacs for mac. I installed using macports.

I located the init file using `describe-variable` and `user-init-file`. I copied into the init file the text

```lisp
(when (eq system-type 'darwin) ;; mac specific settings                         
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'control))
```

as suggested in [this link](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#h5o-32).

But Command key still does not appear to work as a Control key. I don't know if the reason is because I am using Emacs in the terminal. I suspect this is not the issue because when I delete the line `(when (eq system-type 'darwin)` from the init file, I get an error that the line `(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)` is not valid (this also of course seems to imply that the init file is in fact being found and read by Emacs).

I know there are several stack exchange questions on this topic already, but my solution described above is my attempt to implement those answers, and it is not working.

I am running a high sierra operating system, so, fairly old.

Comment: Please add to the question the version of Emacs (C-h v emacs-version RET) and how you installed it

Comment: The reason _is_ because you're running an Emacs in the terminal. Your terminal emulator is capturing your modifiers.